# Cannot delete file programmatically in C# with UAC and admin account

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, permissions, delete-file

I am working on a self-updating system for my application that compares assembly version numbers, then wipes the local directory and copies new server files over. The app has a custom manifest that requires UAC activation, and is being run under an administrative account. Here's the code for deletion:

```
            /* Clear target directory */
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(args[1]);
        foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
        {
            file.Delete();
        }
```

Before this, the process that needs updated files is killed. Here is the console output:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vk8Uh.png)

The program successfully deletes one file, but at the .exe comes crashing to a halt. I've been searching for a solution for hours, can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
```

The process actually has time to end before my updater tried to delete the executable.